# How to find out if a word is automatically autocorrected in Android

Tags: android, error-correction, autocorrect

While typing a text some word are automatically autocorrected when space is pressed. If that happens I want to mark this word.
My problem is I can't find a way to find out when a word is autocorrected.

So my question is how do you find out when a word is automatically autocorrected?

Edit:

I have a TextView and I want to know if there is a possibility to find out if a word was autocorrected while typing a text.

Or is that impossible from inside of the application and only the keyboard can tell if a word was autocorreted? So basically I would need to implement a custom keyboard to know when a word is autokorrected?

Comment: Maybe AutoCompleteText view will be helpful. Let's check:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: Not what i was searching for. But thanks to you I found it! So Thanks! I overlooked or underrated some methods, because AutoCompleteText and TextView have a onCommitCorrection method! And thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: at least I helped somehow. Good you resolved your problem.